# How to make a type available in all namespaces?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

I've made Excel objects available for a class in the usual way:

`using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

However, I'll be developing many classes in this project, most of which will need to work with Excel objects, and it seems like I'd have to put this in the header of every file.  Is there a way for me to somehow enter this `using` statement at the project level, so that I don't have to add it in every file, and make it easier to change if for some reason I decide to start using a different Excel library?

Comment: You do want that using at the top of your file. It tells you something very important about that file. I find that with Resharper installed the pain of maintaining my using block is minimal.

Comment: Even if you did this, you'd have to include using statements for all other namespaces you're using in that file anyway, such as `System`, etc. Then you'd probably think it's a good idea to include everything in a global using directive so all your classes could use it which is just a terrible idea.

Comment: @DaveZych, is it a problem with my class structure if I have a lot of classes that all have the same `using` directive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no such thing as a project-wide `using` directive in C#. You'll need a directive in each file that wants to take advantage of it.

Comment: Right. He could make a global class with all the references in it, but then that class would need to be included everywhere. So they may or may not be any better.